# How can one find and delete a record in a DAO Recordset where two record values are equal to two separate combo boxes on a form

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have an ACCESS 2010 Form:

[image]

The Activity Roster table looks like this:

[image]

I would like to remove a member from a given activity and have developed some code that I think is close, but cannot resolve a critical issue.  I have to find the row in the Activity Roster table that has a record with the ActivityID and MemberID values that correspond to the “Activity Name” combo box and “Remove Member” combo box.  Here is the code:

```html
Private Sub cmdRemoveMember_Click()

Dim MembeID As Long, CutMemID As Long, ActID As Long
Dim db As DAO.Database, rsIn As DAO.Recordset, rsOut As DAO.Recordset
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim strQName As String


CutMemID = Me!cboCutMember.Column(0)  'set the value of CutMemID as the MemberID from the Remove Member combo box
ActID = Me.cboActivityName.Column(0)  'store the ActID from the Activity Name combo box

'query the tblActivityRoster for records with specified Activity ID (Name)- this generates the QActivityMembership query
strQName = "SELECT * FROM [tblActivityRoster] WHERE [ActivityID] = " & ActID
Set rsIn = db.OpenRecordset(strQName, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
rsIn.MoveLast  'this will "populate the recordset"


'prepare to remove a member from the tblActivityRoster
Set rsOut = db.OpenRecordset("tblActivityRoster", dbOpenDynaset, dbEditAdd)
rsOut.MoveLast   'this will "populate the recordset"

With rsOut  'from the tblActivityRoster, find the record where the Activity ID = ActID and MemberID = CutMemID
    Do Until rsOut.EOF
        If rsOut![ActivityID] = ActID And rsOut![MemberID] = CutMemID Then   'THIS IS WHERE IF FAILS!!
            rsOut.Delete
        End If
        rsOut.MoveNext
    Loop

End With

Me.QActivityMembership_subform.Form.Requery

'Now close the query
DoCmd.Close acQuery, strQName

'now clear everything
rsIn.Close
rsOut.Close
Set rsIn = Nothing
Set rsOut = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Would appreciate any help…thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micheal,

Your code looks like it is taking the long way around. Why not just use a DELETE query? Sample:

```
Private Sub cmdRemoveMember_Click()

Dim CutMemID As Long, ActID As Long, strQName As String

Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb

CutMemID = Me!cboCutMember.Column(0)  'set the value of CutMemID as the MemberID from the Remove Member combo box
ActID = Me.cboActivityName.Column(0)  'store the ActID from the Activity Name combo box

' build delete query for Activity and Member
strQName = "DELETE FROM [tblActivityRoster] WHERE ([ActivityID] = " & ActID & ") AND ([MemberID] = " & CutMemID & ");"

' delete all matching records
db.Execute strQName, dbSeeChanges + dbFailOnError

Me.QActivityMembership_subform.Form.Requery

Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Much more straightforward.